# How to not update the data after cancel or close the modal in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ng-modal

> I have created a bootstrap NgModal. In table, after click on edit
> button, it contains a form with some input fields. If I click on save
> it is working fine but If I click on cancel it is closing but also it
> is updating the fields data. I want if I click on cancel it should not
> save the data or update the data.

**app.component.ts**

```
> import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal, NgbModalOptions} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
>     .....
>      constructor(private config: NgbModalConfig, 
>                   private modalService: NgbModal)
>     {
>        config.backdrop = 'static';
>         config.keyboard = false; 
>     } 
>     .....
>     editCharges(event:any, content, aRow, rowIndex){
>         console.log("content of charges: ",content);
>         console.log("aRow: ",aRow);
>         console.log("rowIndex: ",rowIndex);
>         this.chargesDetail = aRow;
>         this.chargesDetail.rowIndex = rowIndex;
>         this.overrideCharges = false;
>         event.target.closest('datatable-body-cell').blur();
>         this.modalService.open(content,{size: 'lg', windowClass: 'modal-xl'}).result.then((result) => {
>             console.log("closed ", result);
>         }, (reason) => {
>           console.log("Charges.dismissed " , reason);
>         });
>       }
```

.....

**app.component.html**

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Actions">
                          <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                            <a *ngIf="loggedInUser.userType !== 'RECEIVER'" class="success p-0" data-original-title="" title="Edit" (click)="editGoods($event, goodsContent,row, rowIndex)">
                                <i class="ft-edit-2 font-large-1 mr-2"></i>
                            </a>

....

 <ng-template #chargesContent let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" [disabled]="!chargesForm.valid" style="margin-right: 6px;" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary" 
            (click)="saveCharges(chargesForm);c('data saved')">
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Save
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning mr-1" data-dismiss='modal' (click)="d('cancel click')"> 
            <i class="ft-x"></i> Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
    
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of save button to 'submit' or transform 'cancel' button in something that isn't a button

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what is mentioned by @davimargelo , you need to define proper behavior for your form, in my opinion, you must also clear the form object after user clicks on cancel button, also I think you must define the handler name properly like given below,

Write this in your ts file,

```
onCancel(): void {
    this.yourFormGroupObject.reset();// This will reset the values defined inside the form
}
```

Comment: I tried but it also resets the saved data like the edited one before. Now the data is blank. which i do not required

Comment: can you show me all your code? I may be able to help better?